# Increment and duplicate voucherNo using regex in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

How do I make a duplicate so that when duplicated it makes an increment of +1 from the initial voucherNo. For example, I have an initial voucher No QUO/2023/06/001 when duplicated becomes QUO/2023/06/001(1) and when I want to duplicate again the initial voucher No QUO/2023/06/001 becomes QUO/2023/06/ 001(2). Because from my code there is an error, if there is already a duplicate voucherNo he doesn't check it. For example, this voucher No QUO/2023/06/001 has been duplicated once, but when I duplicate it again with the original voucher No, the result is still QUO/2023/06/01(1) it should be QUO/2023/06/01(2). What's the solution?

```
const handleDuplicate = () => {
        swal({
            title: 'Confirmation',
            text: 'Are you sure want to duplicate this data?',
            icon: 'warning',
            buttons: [true, 'Duplicate'],
        }).then((succeed) => {

            if (succeed) {
                //const newFormData = { ...formData };
                let newFormData = { ...formData }
                let voucherNo = newFormData.voucherNo;
                let increment = 1;
                const regex = /\((\d+)\)$/;

                newFormData.id = 0;

                newFormData.calculatorDetails = newFormData.calculatorDetails.map((item) => {
                    const detail = { ...item, id: 0 };
                    return detail;
                });

                newFormData.calculatorApprovals = [];
                newFormData.calculatorHistories = [];


                const match = voucherNo.match(regex);
                if (match) {

                    increment = parseInt(match[1]) + 1;

                    voucherNo = voucherNo.replace(regex, '');
                }
                newFormData.voucherNo = `${voucherNo}(${increment})`;

                addData({ url, body: newFormData }).then((res) => {
                    navigate(`${path}/${res.data.id}/edit`);
                });
            }
        });
    };

<div className="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label>Calculation #</label>
                        <input id="calculationInput" className="form-control" type="text" name="voucherNo" value={formData.voucherNo} onChange={isCountReverse ? (e) => onCountReverseChange(e) : (e) => onChange(e)} readOnly />
                    </div>
```